# How to remove unnecessary gaps?

Tags: python, text-files, whitespace

I try to remove line indents and unnecessary. I tried the replace, lstrip () and strip () functions but it didn't work as I thought. Can anyone help me?

my text file

```
 -4   1 0
 -5   2 0
  6  -3 0
 -7   1 0
 -8   2 0
  9  -3 0
-10   1 0
-11   2 0
 12  -3 0
```

strip and lstrip gave me this output

```
-4   1 0
 -5   2 0
  6  -3 0
 -7   1 0
 -8   2 0
  9  -3 0
-10   1 0
-11   2 0
 12  -3 0
```

replace("  ",' ')

```
-4  1 0
 -5  2 0
 6 -3 0
 -7  1 0
 -8  2 0
 9 -3 0
-10  1 0
-11  2 0
 12 -3 0
```

I need:

```
-4 1 0
-5 2 0
6 -3 0
-7 1 0
-8 2 0
9  -3 0
-10 1 0
-11 2 0
12 -3 0
```

demofile.txt

```
>=3 1 2 -3
```

I try to read the file with numbers and edit, and then do the math operations
My full code:

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import math


with open("demofile.txt", "r") as s:
    # read data
    f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    # input preprocessing
    p = 1
     
    for i in list(lines):

        if i[0] != '<' and i[0] != '>' and i[0] != '=':
            d = str(' '.join(i.split()))
            print(d)

        else:
            w = i.replace("=", '')
            w = w.replace(">", '')
            w = w.replace("<", '')
            w = ', '.join(w.split())
            c = np.array([w])
            c1 = [int(i) for i in c[0].replace(" ", "").split(",")]
            # insert input to array
            c1 = np.array(c1)
            # save first value in array
            frst = c1[0]
            # remove first value in array
            c1 = np.delete(c1,0)
            #print(c1)
            # count values in line
            n = len(c1)
            sest2=c1
            #print(c1)
            c1=np.array([c1]*frst)
        
            # max value from demofile
            maxv =  maxv + 1
            if p == 1:
                # last numbers
                end = frst * n + maxv
                l = np.arange(maxv, end)
                arr = l.reshape(frst, n)          
            else:
                end1 = end + frst * n
                l = np.arange(end, end1)
                arr = l.reshape(frst, n)
                end = end1
            

            arr[c1 < 0] *= -1
           # print(arr)
            arr6=np.transpose(arr)*-1 
            sest1=arr6
            #print(arr6)
            #print(sest1,'\n')
            sest = np.zeros((sest1.flatten().shape[0],2))
            sest[:,[0]] = sest1.T.flatten()[:,None]
            sest[:,[1]] = np.tile(sest2,frst)[:,None]
            sest=sest.astype(int)
            #print(sest)
            sest=str(sest).replace("[",'')
            sest=str(sest).replace("]",' 0')            
            sest = sest[:-1]
            sest=str(sest).replace("\n ",'\n')
            #sest=sest.lstrip(" ")
            print(sest)
```

Comment: Please provide your code so that users can show you how to change what you have.

Comment: One option: `" ".join(s.split())` (Where `s` is the line of text) Although, your desired output has an anomaly at `9  -3 0`. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with regex.

```py
import re

(...)

first_pass = re.sub(r' +', ' ', your_text, flags=re.MULTILINE) # Eliminate duplicate whitespaces
final_pass = re.sub(r'^ +', '', first_pass, flags=re.MULTILINE) # Eliminate leading whitespaces

print(final_pass)
```

This outputs:

```
-4 1 0
-4 1 0
-5 2 0
6 -3 0
-7 1 0
-8 2 0
9 -3 0
-10 1 0
-11 2 0
12 -3 0
```